# Only run method when previous method has commited

Tags: java

I have a method which creates a database entry.
After that a second method reads this database entry.

```
public IfdmJob startIfdmRun(Scenario scenario) throws IfdmConfException {
        scenario.valideerVoorIfdm();
        try {
            IfdmJob ifdmJob = createIfdmJob(scenario); // CREATES A JOB ENTRY IN THE DATABASE
            startJob(ifdmJob); // READS THE JOB ENTRY
            return ifdmJob;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to start ifdm run", e);
            throw new IfdmConfException(IfdmConfException.Message.GENERAL);
        }
    }
    
    private void startJob(IfdmJob ifdmJob) {
        ifdmWorkerService.startJob(ifdmJob);
    }
    
    private IfdmJob createIfdmJob(Scenario scenario) throws IOException, InvalidValueException {
        removeRunningIfdmJobs(scenario);
        IfdmRun ifdmRun = new IfdmRun(scenario);
        byte[] zipFile = createIfdmZipFile(ifdmRun);
        IfdmJob ifdmJob = new IfdmJob(scenario, zipFile, userService.getLoggedInUser().getUsername());
        return entiteitService.create(ifdmJob);
    }
```

The problem I am having is that the commit of the createIfdmJob method has not completed yet so the startJob goes to look for the entry but can't find it and cancels the job.

Is their a way in which I can ensure the startjob method only starts when the commit of createIfdmJob has triggered?

Comment: I see your team likes the [smurf naming convention](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/).

Comment: some of our more senior members do have that habit unfortunately. @Philipp

Comment: Are you able to change the classes `IfdmJob` and `IfdmWorkerService`? If not, are they extensions of the standard classes `Runnable` / `ExecutorService`?

Comment: @Philipp yes I am able to alter these classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are apparently implementing multithreading with a bunch of in-house classes like `IfdmJob` and `IfdmWorkerService`. We do not know what your in-house framework can and can't do, but it seems like they replicate the functionality of the Java standard classes [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

The Java standard classes solve this issue by having `ExecutorService.submit(Runnable)` return a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) on which you can then call `.get()` which blocks until the task is completed.

An alternative solution would be to modify `ifdmWorkerService.startJob` to take a `Runnable` as an optional second parameter and have it execute that Runnable when the first job was completed. This pattern is called a [callback method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).